# Crystal Reports only shows the last column

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, crystal-reports

since i am new to crystal report i have search for 3 hours still couldn't find the right answer to my problem.
please check my code.

```
Dim rptsumrep As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
        Dim sda As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim bsource As New BindingSource
        Dim dtincom As New DataTable
        dtincom.Clear()
        conn.Open()
        Dim queryIncom As String = "select *from tblbilling where date_conduct between '" & dtfrom.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "' and '" & dtto.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "'"
        sda = New MySqlDataAdapter(queryIncom, conn)
        sda.Fill(dtincom)
        bsource.DataSource = dtincom
        sda.Update(dtincom)
        grid.DataSource = bsource

        rptsumrep = New CrystalReport1
        rptsumrep.SetDataSource(dtincom)
        frmCrystalReport.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptsumrep
        frmCrystalReport.CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
        frmCrystalReport.ShowDialog()
        frmCrystalReport.Dispose()
```

Questions:

1. do i have to name my rpt field same to my datagridview column title?
2. why is it the last column title same as my database which i rename it as "Status" but on the run time it shows "status"

Comment: Are your column titles the same in your database and in your dataset? Try to write all the column names insted of using Select *

Comment: nope it did not match only the status is matching from database and data set only caps are different.

Comment: Try to make them the same

Comment: okay ill try. be back

Comment: @Hoh hey it works Thank You. but is it ok if i edit the title?

Comment: You can edit titles in Report, don't do it in Database or Dataset, since those two has to match. Do you mind if I add that as a answer to your question?

Comment: of course you can. you deserve it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column titles in Database and Dataset has to be the same.
Also, using `Select Column1, Column2, ColumnN ...` is always the better way than writing just `Select *` in query.
Titles should/can be edited in `Report file`, which will change the showing title of that column, of course the name of the column should stay as a original in Details section of report.